# What does "two eye fulls" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A year in the making, the full six minute stopmotion short features the voice of Josie Long, one zillion hand carved tiny things, literally tens of carved foam puppets, **two eye fulls** of in-camera, long-exposure light trickery and a pair of tiny dolphins, smooching.

Source: The description of the stop motion short *Marilyn Myller*

Answer (score 2):

It's an expression that essentially means "a lot of."  It's a bit of an odd way of stating it, a more common version is "an eye full."